# Make scale_y_log10 to have the tickmarks at 0.01,0.1,1

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wrote the following code to make the plot

```
pd<- position_dodge(.2)  # # move them .05 to the left and right
pm25 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=CombSEG, y=conc,shape=A,color=A, lty=A,     group=A)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_line() +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=conc-se, ymax=conc+se),
              width=.1, position=pd) +
theme_bw()+
limits(c(0
scale_y_log10(breaks=c(0.01,0.1,1),labels=c(0.01,0.1,1))
```

The automatic scale breaks are 10^-1.8, 10^-1.6, 10^-1.4 ... 10^-0.4.   I would actually like the lowest tick to be 0.01 and the highest tickmark is 1.

Thank you for your help.

Edits:  Here is what the plot look like after I tried your code.
[image]

Comment: Could you give a small reproducible example (ie data)? Even if you just make some up that simulates your problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `breaks` and `labels` arguments of `scale_y_log10` (read about them [here](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_continuous.html)).

```
# make up some sample data
df <- data.frame(x=1:100,y=10^-(2*runif(100)))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + scale_y_log10()
```

Looks like:
[image]

Then to modify the log10 scale to have custom breaks at .01, .1 and 1, use the `breaks` argument:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + scale_y_log10(breaks=c(.01,.1,1))
```

Looks like:
[image]

Finally, if you want the labels to also be 0.1, .1 and 1, use the `labels` argument:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + 
          scale_y_log10(breaks=c(.01,.1,1),labels=c(.01,.1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the exact same code but only 0.1 showed up in the middle. Here is the maximum and minimum of the data
    Min.   :0.01504
    Median :0.03957
    Mean   :0.06148
    Max.   :0.43815

Comment: I had another set of data where Min=0.1 and Max=.7 and the only 0.1 showed up near the end of the scale.

Comment: @TranHuynh If your data range from 0.1 to 0.7 and you manually set the breaks at 0.01, 0.1 and 1, why would you possibly expect to see any of them except 0.1? If you had done as asked and provided a reproducible example, we could have told you from the start to also pass `limits = c(0,1)` to `scale_y_log10`. We're not mind readers.

Comment: @ mathematical.coffee & Joran & Thierry:  Thank you.

Comment: In this case I think I like `coord_trans(y="log10")` better, as suggested in another answer. See the [coord_trans doc](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/coord_trans.html) at the new ggplot2 doc site.

Answer (score 17):

Use coord_trans() instead of scale()

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:100,y=10^-(2*runif(100)))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + coord_trans(y = "log10")
```

[image]