# Custom y-axis labels in ggplot2 with log transformed co-ordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to draw a nice line plot with lower and upper bounds shown courtesy of geom_ribbon - see below:

```
ggplot(data = inflow, aes(x = tt, y = inflow.mean)) + geom_line(size = 1) + 
geom_ribbon(eb, alpha = 0.5) + coord_trans(y = "log")
```

Could someone please advise me on how I could make the y-axis labels look prettier?

I would like to show: `0, 1, 10, 100` etc.

Note: in searching the internet, it would appear that for geom_ribbon, coord_trans must be used to have a log scale.

Comment: You do not provide a working example of your problem, nor a picture that illustrates for lack of a working example. But anyway: how does `coord_trans(y = "log10")` work out? Or `scale_y_log10()` instead of coord_trans? Also note: "The difference between transforming the scales and transforming the coordinate system is that scale transformation occurs BEFORE statistics, and coordinate transformation afterwards." (from the coord_trans doc).

Comment: Did you have a look at [this answer]( http://stackoverflow.com/a/9223257/893243?). You could also just wrap `inflow.mean` with `log(inflow.mean)`. If this doesn't solve your problem you would have to provide more info on your data.

Comment: Thanks all. I have since found a solution that has worked. Jase_ - I wrapped my variables as you suggested and used my own wrapped y axis labels: lab <- log(c(0.01, 1.01, 5.01, 10.01, 20.01, 50.01))
names <- c(0,1,5,10,20,50 )

ggplot(data = inflow, aes(x = tt, y = inflow.mean)) + geom_line(size = 1) + geom_ribbon(eb, alpha = 0.5) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = lab, labels = names)

Comment: @mjburns you should post your comment as an answer to your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Jase_ - I wrapped my variables as you suggested and used my own wrapped y axis labels:

```
lab <- log(c(0.01, 1.01, 5.01, 10.01, 20.01, 50.01)) 
names <- c(0,1,5,10,20,50 )
ggplot(data = inflow, aes(x = tt, y = inflow.mean)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) + geom_ribbon(eb, alpha = 0.5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = lab, labels = names)
```